# Sending commands to browser

Tags: java

Hi I want to send url links from a Java application to a browser in Windows 7. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "send url links" you mean open a URL in a browser, this should work for you:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

// ...

if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
{
    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.example.com"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just launch a browser to a certain URL, I'd recommend just using the Java APIs for launching a new process, and use the Windows `start` command.

Try opening a cmd.exe and running `start http://google.com` - you basically would just do that from your Java app using the process APIs, which you should be able to find a good tutorial on, if needed.

If you are asking about manipulating an existing browser window from another application, then your answer is going to be much more complicated.

Comment: thank you for replying. This is another alternative way to solve this problem. Thats creating child process and execute command.